# Implement a function in a specific line of a file

Tags: python

I have a program where I open a file (previous written), "copy" the first seven lines and write them into a new, empty file. After that is completed, I have to access the 7th line of my file and implement a function on it.

```
def write_assignments_file(file_name):
    inFile = open(file_name, 'r')
    header = list(islice(inFile, 7))
    outFile = open('kk.txt', 'w')
    for item in header:
        outFile.write(item)

    data = outFile.readlines()
    dateTime.add_minutes(data[7], 5)

    inFile.close()
    outFile.close()
```

dateTime is a .py file where I have the function add_minutes(hm, incr). Basically, it increments "incr" minutes into a given time, "hm".
The 7th line of my outFile file has only a hour in the format HH:MM. I want to increment 5 minutes (using my add_minutes function) into that time, but I can't. I keep getting this error:

```
data = outFile.readlines()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Can anyone tell me where are the mistakes in my code? I believe is related with the fact that I'm trying to read a file while I opened it with the "write" option. Although, I don't see any other option besides closing that file and re-opening it in "read" option. But in that way, I believe I won't replace the previous hour in the file with the one after being affected by the add_minutes function.

Comment: You have to use `inFile`, not `outFile`.

Comment: Why do you copy 7 lines into a new file anyway if you just need to add minnuts to the 7nth line ? You could return every 7nth line of a new file that goes into your 'write_assignment_file' function and return it to your next function 'add_minutes' without reading it from another file.

Comment: You also have an ‘off by one‘ error in data[7], use data[-1] to grab the last item